# Passing mutable Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd >& into function via reference

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen, eigen3

While trying to mimic a Python Code in CPP (With Eigen)

Python Code :

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy.linalg import inv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import cos, sin, pi


def G(y,t): 
    a1d, a2d = y[0], y[1]
    a1, a2 = y[2], y[3]

    m11, m12 = (m1+m2)*l1, m2*l2*cos(a1-a2)
    m21, m22 = l1*cos(a1-a2), l2
    m = np.array([[m11, m12],[m21, m22]])

    f1 = -m2*l2*a2d*a2d*sin(a1-a2) - (m1+m2)*g*sin(a1)
    f2 = l1*a1d*a1d*sin(a1-a2) - g*sin(a2)
    f = np.array([f1, f2])

    accel = inv(m).dot(f)

    return np.array([accel[0], accel[1], a1d, a2d])


def RK4_step(y, t, dt):
    k1 = G(y,t)
    k2 = G(y+0.5*k1*dt, t+0.5*dt)
    k3 = G(y+0.5*k2*dt, t+0.5*dt)
    k4 = G(y+k3*dt, t+dt)

    return dt * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4) /6

# variables
m1, m2 = 2.0, 1.0
l1, l2 = 1.0, 2.0
g = 9.81

delta_t = 0.01
time = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, delta_t)

# initial state
y = np.array([0,0,0,1.0])   # [velocity, displacement]

Y1 = []
Y2 = []

# time-stepping solution
for t in time:
    y = y + RK4_step(y, t, delta_t) 

    Y1.append(y[2])
    Y2.append(y[3])


# plot the result
plt.plot(time,Y1)
plt.plot(time,Y2)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['Angle1', 'Angle2'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Source : https://github.com/apf99/Double-Pendulum/blob/master/d_pen.py (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBBQKZb6JZk)

Being a Noob to C++ and Eigen.

Transcribed Code in C++ :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<Eigen/Eigen>
#include<fstream>
// grc : gravitational constant

#define grc 9.81


// solving for acceleration
void G(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& dummy2, const double& t, const double& m1, const double& m2, const double& l1, const double& l2, Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector4d>& k){
  // angular velocities (av1, av2) and displacements (a1, a2),
  double av1, av2, a1, a2;
  // angular velocities
  av1 = dummy2[0];
  av2 = dummy2[1];
  // angular position
  a1 = dummy2[3];
  a2 = dummy2[4];

  // Defiing the mass like matrix
  Eigen::Matrix2d A;
  A<<(m1+m2)*l1, m2*l2*std::cos(a1-a2),  l1*std::cos(a1-a2), l2;
  // Defining the forcing like function
  Eigen::Vector2d F, acceleration;
  F<<-m2 * l2 * av2*av2*std::sin(a1-a2) - (m1+m2)*grc*std::sin(a1), l1*av1*av1*std::sin(a1-a2) - grc*std::sin(a2);

  // product of the inverse mass and forcing function
  acceleration = (A.inverse()) * F;

  //assiging the values
  k(0) = acceleration(0);
  k(1) = acceleration(1);
  k(2) = av1;
  k(3) = av2;
   
}

// attempt to pass by refernce
// Ranga Kutta 4
void RK4(const Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>& dummy, const double& t, const double& dt, const double& m1, const double& m2, const double& l1, const double& l2){
  Eigen::Vector4d k1 , k2 , k3 , k4 ;
  G(dummy, t, m1, m2, l1, l2, k1);
  G(dummy+ 0.5 * dt * k1, t+0.5*dt, m1, m2, l1, l2, k2);
  G(dummy+ 0.5 * dt * k2, t+0.5*dt, m1, m2, l1, l2, k3);
  G(dummy+ dt * k3, t+dt, m1, m2, l1, l2, k4);

  dummy = (dt/6.0) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2* k3 + k4);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

  // m1 and m2 are the masses of the pendulum 
  double m1 = 2.0, m2 = 1.0;
  // l1 and l2 are the lengths of the masses
  double l1 = 1.0, l2 = 2.0;
  // time delta
  double dt = 0.01;
  // Defining the angular displacement y(2), y(3) and  angular velocities y(0), y(1)
  Eigen::VectorXd y(4), y_dummy(4);
  y(0) = 0.0;
  y(1) = 0.0;
  y(2) = 0.0;
  y(3) = 1.0;

  // time as t
  double t = 0.0;

  //file opening to write data
  std::fstream pend("double_pendulum.dat",std::ios::out|std::ios::app);
  //position and velocity are written to the dat file
  pend<<"v(x)  v(y) p(x) p(y) \n";
  
  // time ; stepping
  for(unsigned i = 0; i<1000;i++){
    t += i/100;
    y_dummy = y;
    RK4(y_dummy,t,dt, m1, m2, l1, l2);
    y += y_dummy;
    pend<<(y.transpose())<<std::endl;
  }

  pend.close();
  return 0;
  
}
```

When compiled with
`g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/include/eigen3 -o dp dp.cpp`

The following errors popup (The jist of the error is mentioned below)

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >’
   43 |   G(dummy, t, m1, m2, l1, l2, k1);

etc .. etc.. etc.
```

**for each non const reference and matrix passed.**

**When either or both are defined as const, they become immutable, hence the vector will not be updated.**

Being completely flabbergasted by [Eigen_tux documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html)  , what could be the solution in layman's terms.

Or, are there libraries that can perform this task in a simple manner?

*PS : Couldn't compile the script completely*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mutable reference, more precisely an l-value reference, only ever points at an existing, named object (the actual language rules are of course more complicated but that is the intention). The `Eigen::Ref` object is not one of those since it is created as a temporary object in the function call. Therefore the compiler refuses to create such a reference.

As a consequence, it is customary to pass inputs as `const Eigen::Ref<const Matrix>&`  and input/outputs as `Eigen::Ref<Matrix>`. The function signature should look like this:

```
void G(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& dummy2,
    double t, double m1, double m2, double l1, double l2,
    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector4d> k);
```

Note that the `Ref` object functionally references the original matrix or matrix block. It doesn't need to be a reference in the C++ sense to do this. You could also pass the input `Eigen::Ref<const Matrix>` by value. However, this would introduce a slight loss in performance if you continue to pass that `Ref` to a sub-function, since it would create a new copy.

For mutable references we accept that cost for consistency and because mutable `Ref`s are actually cheaper objects than `Ref<const Matrix>`. The reason being that const-Refs copy their inputs if the inner stride would not be 1, e.g. when you pass a single row of a matrix as a `Ref<const Vector>`. This is described in the [Ref documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Ref.html).

Note also that passing simple doubles as const reference is pointless. Pass-by-value for scalars is more efficient.

### Fully fixed code

Here is a full version that compiles and does not produce runtime errors. I've marked all changes with `CHANGE` and further notes as `NOTE`.

```
#include<iostream>
// NOTE: You mix C's sin() and cos() with std::sin() and std::cos()
#include<math.h>
#include<Eigen/Eigen>
#include<fstream>
// grc : gravitational constant

#define grc 9.81


// solving for acceleration
void G(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Vector4d>& dummy2,
       double t, double m1, double m2, double l1, double l2,
       Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector4d> k){
  // angular velocities (av1, av2) and displacements (a1, a2),
  double av1, av2, a1, a2;
  // CHANGE: Using convenience methods x(), y(), z() and w() to
  // access the first 4 indices
  // angular velocities
  av1 = dummy2.x();
  av2 = dummy2.y();
  // angular position
  a1 = dummy2.z();
  a2 = dummy2.w();

  // Defining the mass like matrix
  Eigen::Matrix2d A;
  // NOTE: x * cos(y - z) can be numerically unstable if a1 ~ a2
  // Herbie (https://herbie.uwplse.org) suggests
  // x * (cos(y) * cos(z) + sin(y) * sin(z)) or FMA variations thereof.
  // Same with x * sin(y - z) being better computed as
  // x * (sin(y) * cos(z) - cos(y) * sin(z))
  // in fact you can conveniently compute both as
  // std::polar(x, y) * std::conj(std::polar(1., z))
  // With x * cos(y - z) as the real part and x * sin(y - z) as the imag part
  // You may also want to clean up all those redundant calls to sin
  // and cos instead of putting yourself at the mercy of the compiler
  // for doing so
  A<<(m1+m2)*l1, m2*l2*std::cos(a1-a2),
    l1*std::cos(a1-a2), l2;
  // Defining the forcing like function
  Eigen::Vector2d F, acceleration;
  F<<-m2 * l2 * av2*av2*std::sin(a1-a2) - (m1+m2)*grc*std::sin(a1),
    l1*av1*av1*std::sin(a1-a2) - grc*std::sin(a2);

  // product of the inverse mass and forcing function
  // CHANGE: Using noalias() for matrix multiplication. See documentation
  // NOTE: The usual warnings about using the inverse instead of solvers
  // apply. See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html
  acceleration.noalias() = (A.inverse()) * F;

  //assigning the values
  // CHANGE: Reduced lines of code
  k.head<2>() = acceleration;
  k.tail<2>() = dummy2.head<2>();
   
}

// attempt to pass by refernce
// Ranga Kutta 4
// CHANGE: Made dummy input mutable and made size explicit
void RK4(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector4d> dummy, double t, double dt,
     double m1, double m2, double l1, double l2){
  Eigen::Vector4d k1 , k2 , k3 , k4 ;
  G(dummy, t, m1, m2, l1, l2, k1);
  G(dummy+ 0.5 * dt * k1, t+0.5*dt, m1, m2, l1, l2, k2);
  G(dummy+ 0.5 * dt * k2, t+0.5*dt, m1, m2, l1, l2, k3);
  G(dummy+ dt * k3, t+dt, m1, m2, l1, l2, k4);

  dummy = (dt/6.0) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2* k3 + k4);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

  // m1 and m2 are the masses of the pendulum 
  double m1 = 2.0, m2 = 1.0;
  // l1 and l2 are the lengths of the masses
  double l1 = 1.0, l2 = 2.0;
  // time delta
  double dt = 0.01;
  // Defining the angular displacement y(2), y(3) and  angular velocities y(0), y(1)
  // CHANGE: Simplified assignment to y. Simplified type
  Eigen::Vector4d y(0., 0., 0., 1.), y_dummy;

  // time as t
  double t = 0.0;

  //file opening to write data
  std::fstream pend("double_pendulum.dat",std::ios::out|std::ios::app);
  //position and velocity are written to the dat file
  pend<<"v(x)  v(y) p(x) p(y) \n";
  
  // time ; stepping
  for(unsigned i = 0; i<1000;i++){
    t += i/100;
    y_dummy = y;
    RK4(y_dummy,t,dt, m1, m2, l1, l2);
    y += y_dummy;
    pend<<(y.transpose())<<std::endl;
  }

  pend.close();
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Solved the a main problem, the code compiled, but, there is a run time error ```/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:163: Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::CoeffReturnType Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::operator[](Eigen::Index) const [with Derived = Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >; CoeffReturnType = double; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `index >= 0 && index < size()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)```. Changing other functions too throws` errors.

Comment: **gdb output** *after a2 = dummy2[4];*  **inside the function G**  ` /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:163: Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::CoeffReturnType Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::operator[](Eigen::Index) const [with Derived = Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >; CoeffReturnType = double; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `index >= 0 && index < size()' failed `

Comment: in **G(dummy+ 0.5 * dt * k1, t+0.5*dt, m1, m2, l1, l2, k2); ** `const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, const Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >, const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> > >`

Comment: @A-Z'sh Your indices when accessing ```dummy2``` in ```G``` are off by one. ```a2 = dummy[4]``` would require a 5 element vector but you only pass 4 elements

Comment: Thanks for the catch. . in `G(dummy+ ((0.5 * dt) * k1), t+(0.5*dt), m1, m2, l1, l2, k2);` and subsequent functions  spurts **error**,  ``const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, const Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >, const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >, const Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> > >`. _Removed all const Matrices, vectors and doubles_, then **const conversion error ??**

Comment: @A-Z'sh You probably just had the ```dummy2``` argument to ```RK4``` as const but since I don't see your current attempt to fix your code, I included a full, working version

Comment: `void G(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector4d> dummy2, double t, double m1, double m2, double l1, double l2,  Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector4d> k);`  and `void RK4(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Vector4d> dummy, double t, double dt, double m1, double m2, double l1, double l2);` are the declerations

Comment: @A-Z'sh You cannot have the first argument to ```G``` be a mutable ```Ref```. You try to pass an expression like ```dummy + 0.5 * dt * k1```. That can only be converted to a ```Ref<const ...>```