# Passing references to Eigen::MatrixXd blocks to functions efficiently

Tags: c++, eigen, numerical-methods, eigen3

I have implemented a C++ function based on the Eigen library with the following signature:

```
myfunc(const Eigen::ArrayXd& D, const Eigen::ArrayXd& z, Eigen::VectorXd& L, Eigen::MatrixXd& Q)
```

The function takes as inputs arrays D and z and as outputs a VectorXd L and a MatrixXd Q. L and Q will be overwritten with the solution computed by the function.

The function `myfunc` is called by another function which operates with large arrays and matrices. Only parts of a matrix/array must be passed to `myfunc` using the block/segment operators in Eigen. However, I found myself struggling quite a bit with this and have come up with a very suboptimal solution.

The current version of my code works by creating a copy of the blocks I need and passing those to the function:

```
// This is very inefficient as the arrays and matrices are large!
Eigen::ArrayXd D1 = D_part.head(nnz);
Eigen::ArrayXd z1 = z_part.head(nnz);
Eigen::VectorXd L1 = L.head(nnz);
Eigen::MatrixXd Q1 = Q.topLeftCorner(nnz, nnz);
    
myfunc(D1, z1, L1, Q1);
    
D_part.head(nnz) = D1;
z_part.head(nnz) = z1;
L.head(nnz) = L1;
Q.topLeftCorner(nnz, nnz) = Q1;
```

What I would essentially want is this:

```
// No need to create copies!
myfunc(D_part.head(nnz), z_part.head(nnz), L.head(nnz), Q.topLeftCorner(nnz,nnz));
```

I tried working with the `Eigen::Ref<xxx>` class but I had no success.

I tried looking through the documentation but with no success.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

#### Edit 1:

Here is a minimal working example of what is going wrong.

Consider the following snippet:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

int myfunc(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd>& M){
    M = Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones(M.rows(), M.cols());
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    Eigen::MatrixXd M = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(10, 10);
    myfunc(M.topLeftCorner(5, 5));
    std::cout << M;
}
```

The goal of the above snippet is to overwrite the top left quadrant of the matrix with 1s. Not all the matrix has to be passed as reference to the `myfunc` function. This however throws the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:11:27: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >’
   11 |     myfunc(M.topLeftCorner(5, 5));
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /home/mferrari/spack/opt/spack/linux-rocky8-zen2/gcc-11.2.0/eigen-3.4.0-xvepptisxttixdb3wrhpvzngce2xfeir/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:308,
                 from /home/mferrari/spack/opt/spack/linux-rocky8-zen2/gcc-11.2.0/eigen-3.4.0-xvepptisxttixdb3wrhpvzngce2xfeir/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/home/mferrari/spack/opt/spack/linux-rocky8-zen2/gcc-11.2.0/eigen-3.4.0-xvepptisxttixdb3wrhpvzngce2xfeir/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:307:30: note:   after user-defined conversion: ‘Eigen::Ref<PlainObjectType, Options, StrideType>::Ref(const Eigen::DenseBase<OtherDerived>&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(bool)(typename Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Ref<PlainObjectType, RefOptions, StrideType> >::match<Derived>::MatchAtCompileTime), Derived>::type*) [with Derived = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false>; PlainObjectType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; int Options = 0; StrideType = Eigen::OuterStride<>; typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(bool)(typename Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Ref<PlainObjectType, RefOptions, StrideType> >::match<Derived>::MatchAtCompileTime), Derived>::type = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false>; typename Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Ref<PlainObjectType, RefOptions, StrideType> >::match<Derived> = Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::match<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false> >]’
  307 |     EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC inline Ref(const DenseBase<Derived>& expr,
      |                              ^~~
test.cpp:5:41: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int myfunc(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >&)’
    5 | int myfunc(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd>& M){
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Which is sort of expected as `topLeftCorner` returns an rvalue.

Is there really no way to pass a block of a matrix without creating a copy?

Comment: What do you mean you had no success with `Eigen::Ref`? Please show the code that you tried. `Eigen::Ref` was built exactly for this use case

Comment: @Homer512 I added some more context with a minimal example to reproduce the problem. I hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990388/passing-mutable-eigenrefeigenvectorxd-into-function-via-reference/73992785#73992785 Basically, the mutable `Eigen::Ref<>` needs to be passed by value, not by reference. The immutable `Eigen::Ref<const …>` is passed by const-reference

Comment: Ah now I see. I was very confused as the examples in the documentation pass the Eigen::Ref object as a reference, but now I realise I was looking and const examples. Thank you!

Comment: The first answer you gave me solved my issue. Please post that as an answer so that I can accept it.